# Unable to node debugger in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emacs, node-debugger

Unable to run node debugger in vs code, whenever running debugger, terminal opening Emacs
screen like this

[image]

Now, I am stuck, restarted the system, restarted the terminal but unable to close the emacs.

Comment: I can't tell if that's `emacs` or `info`, but my first guess is the latter, mostly because running emacs and asking it to run its info command (which would be an extremely specific request) would be far weirder than something running `info` (which I can imagine being more accidental).

Comment: You would usually quit `info` with `q` btw; although if the situation you've found yourself in was allowing info to receive keyboard inputs then `C-x C-c` would also have worked (and I presume that was how you were trying to exit "emacs"); so I suspect `q` isn't actually going to work for you here.

Comment: I didn't find any solution. I tried installing uninstalling, but nothing worked out. 
At the end, I created a new profile in my mac book, installed the vs code and then it worked fine.